# searchBar not searching

Tags: swift, search

I have viewed some example code of searchBar and followed it to the tee, but my searchBar is not working.  I have a Master-Detail app, and the search is on the Master which has a searchBar and a UITableView.  Whenever I type in anything, I expect the tableview to lessen to show.  Example when I type in "G", it should show "Gerbera" or any flowers that starts with "G".

```
enter code here


//
//  MasterViewController.swift
//  SplitView3
//
//  Created by Sheryll See on 2017-09-28.
//  Copyright © 2017 Sheryll See. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


public class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var tableView: UITableView? = nil
var objects = [Any]()


var siteAddressesRed: [String]?
var siteAddressesBlue: [String]?
var siteDetailRed: [String]?
var siteDetailBlue: [String]?


let kSectionCount:Int = 2
let kRedSection: Int = 0
let kBlueSection: Int = 1

let redFlowers: [String] = ["Gerbera", "Peony", "Rose", "Poppy"]
let blueFlowers: [String] = ["Hyacinth", "Hydrangea", "Sea Holly", "Phlox", "Iris"]
let allFlowers: [String] = ["Gerbera", "Peony", "Rose", "Poppy", "Hyacinth", "Hydrangea", "Sea Holly", "Phlox", "Iris"]

var filteredData = [String]()
var isSearching = false


struct MyVariables {
    static var urlString: [String]? = ["something"]
    static var flowerImage: UIImage?
}



override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    siteAddressesRed = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera",
                        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony",
                        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose",
                        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy"]
    siteAddressesBlue = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth",
                         "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrangea",
                         "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Holly",
                         "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlox",
                         "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris"]

    siteDetailRed = ["Coquitlam1",
                  "Coquitlam2",
                  "Coquitlam3",
                  "Coquitlam4"]
    siteDetailBlue = ["Coquitlam1",
                     "Coquitlam2",
                     "Coquitlam3",
                     "Coquitlam4",
                     "Coquitlam5"]


    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    filteredData = allFlowers




    if let split = splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as!
            UINavigationController).topViewController
            as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
    objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView?.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    //tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}

// MARK: - Segues




public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {


    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        do {
            MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesRed![indexPath.row]]
            MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: redFlowers[indexPath.row])
            // MyVariables.flowerImage = [UIImage(named: "Rose.png")!]
            print("Im here")
        }


    case 1:
        do {
            MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesBlue![indexPath.row]]
            MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: blueFlowers[indexPath.row])
            print("Im there")

        }

    default:
        do {
            MyVariables.urlString = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/flowers"]
            MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: redFlowers[indexPath.row])
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                      sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

       if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesRed![indexPath.row]]
                    MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: redFlowers[indexPath.row])
                   // MyVariables.flowerImage = [UIImage(named: "Rose.png")!]


                }
            case 1:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesBlue![indexPath.row]]
                    MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: blueFlowers[indexPath.row])


                }
            default:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/flowers"]
                    MyVariables.flowerImage = UIImage(named: redFlowers[indexPath.row])
                }
            }


            /*
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController
                as! DetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = MyVariables.urlString as [String]! as AnyObject
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
                splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton
                = true */
        }



    let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController
        as! DetailViewController

    controller.detailItem = MyVariables.urlString as [String]! as AnyObject
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
        splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton
        = true
    }
}





// MARK: - Table View



public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return kSectionCount
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    switch section {
    case kRedSection:
        return redFlowers.count
        return filteredData.count
    case kBlueSection:
        return blueFlowers.count
        return filteredData.count
    default:
        return 0
        return filteredData.count
    }

    if isSearching {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    return filteredData.count


}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case kRedSection:
        return "Red"
    case kBlueSection:
        return "Blue"
    default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}






public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                             for: indexPath)

    //cell.textLabel!.text = siteNames![indexPath.row]

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case kRedSection:
    do {   cell.textLabel!.text = redFlowers[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = siteDetailRed![indexPath.row]
        if isSearching {
                        cell.textLabel!.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
                        }
        else {
                        cell.textLabel!.text = redFlowers[indexPath.row]
        }


        }
    case kBlueSection:
        do {
        cell.textLabel!.text = blueFlowers[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = siteDetailBlue![indexPath.row]
            if isSearching {
                cell.textLabel!.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
                cell.textLabel!.text = blueFlowers[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    default:
        do {
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Unknown"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Unknown"
            if isSearching {
                cell.textLabel!.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
                cell.textLabel!.text = redFlowers[indexPath.row]
            }

        }
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

    let test = UIImage(named: cell.textLabel!.text!)!
    cell.imageView!.image = test

    MyVariables.flowerImage = test



    return cell
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}




    public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
// When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
// When user has entered text into the search box
// Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
// For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
// item should NOT be included
filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? allFlowers : allFlowers.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
    // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
    return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
})

tableView?.reloadData()
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer to this.  I don't have an IBOutlet for the tableView, and I had to delete the searchBar IBOutlet and re-bind it again to the searchBar.